# Facebook App Request, having error when adding 'education' in the app scope

Tags: facebook

This Works:

```
<?php
$APPID = '000000000000000';
$APPSECRET = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
$CANVASSPAGE = 'https://apps.facebook.com/appname/';

$AppScope = 'publish_stream,create_event,user_birthday';
?>
```

This Doesn't Work:

```
<?php
$APPID = '000000000000000';
$APPSECRET = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
$CANVASSPAGE = 'https://apps.facebook.com/appname/';

$AppScope = 'publish_stream,create_event,user_birthday,education';
?>
```

And I get the error message:

Error: An error occurred. Please try again later.

If you notice the only difference on these 2 is I added 'education' on the app scope in the latter then throws an error upon app request.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `education` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)!

[`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object have `education` field, however appropriate permissions to access this field is:

- `user_education_history` – for user itself
- `friends_education_history` – for user's friends